# How get the div of one to spill on the other

Tags: css, wordpress, html, layer

I wanted to create a wordpress website and stumbled upon this page design ( which is not a wordpress one) https://www.refersion.com/pricing

How can I create a custom css for the in_content to spill to .texture2. as seen in the page, pricing tables spilling over to the page title.

thnx in advance

Comment: Actually this page is an "illusion". Two divs aren't spilling over. The main containing div has the blue background that only goes down so far, and then inside is the title div (just text), and the under that (but still over the blue background) is the content div.

Answer (score 1):

To the texture 2 div, add the following CSS property:

```
position:relative and overflow:visible
```

Now to the in_content div, add the following CSS rules:

```
margin-top: -30px; //you can adjust the px value to suit your preference
position: absolute;
```

It should spill over now.

Comment: Also please change the wording of your question so that it follows good naming practice. Maybe you could call it, "Getting a div to spill into another"

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin-bottom on top div. Quick example:

```
<div style='width: 200px; height: 100px; margin-bottom: -50px; background-color: red;'>
Lala
</div>
<div style='width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;'>
Lala
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yM2u5/